# Set the position of qrbox in top using camera with full screen

Tags: javascript, html5-qrcode

I'm using the scanner with camera opened in full screem.

I would like to put the qrbox on top position of window and not in the center.

It's possible to move the qrbox?

The JS I'm using is html5-qrcode: https://github.com/mebjas/html5-qrcode

Screenshot: [image]